# How to know what is background animated image

Tags: javascript, html, css, flash

At squaretrade.com , after logging into the site, I see that there is some animation in the background of the text `"NEW iPHONE?
PROTECT IT FOR LESS THAN $5 A MONTH"`. 
I would love to know how this was done. Is it a flash image or an animated image? Can we copy it and use it in another site?

Thanks & Regards,

Decent Guy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a image. It is video, you can find in this https://resource.squaretrade.com/video/video-homepage-1272x566-v1.mp4

Comment: Thank you very much sir. Would love to know how you have got this out.

Comment: You are welcome mate. If you right click on the animation that you mentioned (actually the video) you will see inspect option in the list. Then click the inspect. You can see the div and it's content inside the div. All you have to do is scan the code. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can able to see //resource.squaretrade.com/htm/css/animate/animate.css. But could not find out that its an video. How exactly you have taken out the link " https://resource.squaretrade.com/video/video-homepage-1272x566-v1.mp4"